# Doesn't my form inherit from a base form class?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

When I define an event in a form, `Visual Studio 2012 Express` creates code like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, _
                              e As EventArgs) _
                          Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

There is no mention here that `Form1` inherits from a base form class. However, in this case, it is not clear where `Form1` gets all it's properties from. What is really going on: is inheritance taking place? if yes, then why is it not shown?

Comment: It inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. The fact that you don´t see it in your code is due to the Form1 class is partial and splitted amongst at least two files. How you make it visible: In the Solution Explorer check the `Show All Files` option. The file `Form1.Designer.vb` should be visible now. When you open it you should see the partial declaration of `Form1` and the inheritance to `Form`.

Comment: Look for partial class Form1 in file `Form1.Designer.vb`. In Solution Explorer you have to click `Show all files`.

Comment: @AlexB. Your comment should be the accepted answer. Please make it an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Forms, like your Form1, inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.
The fact that you don´t see it in your code is due to the `Form1` class is partial and splitted amongst at least two files.

How to make it visible:

- In the Solution Explorer check the `Show All Files` option.
- The file `Form1.Designer.vb` should be visible now.
- When you open it you should see the partial declaration of `Form1` and the inheritance to
  `Form`.